# initialize a default key value pair while returning RedisTemplate object in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis

I am trying to set the default key value pair while returning the `redisTemplate` from below chunk of code. Please help me if it is possible.

```
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    redisTemplate.setExposeConnection(true);
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());

    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    return redisTemplate;
}
```

It should be look something like that:
[image]

Comment: I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

before `return` statement add below two lines.

```
redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
redisTemplate.boundSetOps("myKey").add("user");
```

So the complete code would be:

```
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    redisTemplate.setExposeConnection(true);
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());

    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
    redisTemplate.boundSetOps("myKey").add("user");
    return redisTemplate;
}
```